# Signature verification failed in anchor while testing

Tags: anchor, transactions, solana-program

I'm getting This error

```
Is initialized!:
     Error: Signature verification failed
      at Transaction.serialize (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/transaction.ts:736:13)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/provider.ts:145:22)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Object.rpc [as initialize] (node_modules/@project-serum/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)
```

with this tests

```
describe("testContract", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.TestContract as Program<TestContract>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const key = new PublicKey("U4NHM8DNT3kCNrRtB9ymgt1mcR6RBaHwUHWLoxM4KTF")
     const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts( {
      sender : key
    }).rpc();
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

And the contract is correct and was working before I added an account field to it

```
#[program]
pub mod test_contract {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        let hi = &ctx.accounts.sender.to_account_info().key();
        msg!("{}",hi);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    ///CHECK : Not dangerous
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    pub sender: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about anchor, but you appear to be passing a `PublicKey` where a `Keypair` is needed.  Public keys cannot produce signatures, the corresponding private key is needed for that

Comment: Not passsing kepair anywhere, just passing sender as a account

Comment: which is precisely what i said is the problem

Comment: trent is correct--
you need a keypair to sign. in anchor test you need to add `.signer([keypair])` to your `initialize` method.

i created an example for you on solpg: https://beta.solpg.io/63f777d067edfe0f001069d1

Answer (score 2):

Try using your local keypair that you've got configured with Anchor to test:

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);
const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

const tx = await program.methods.initialize()
    .accounts( {
        sender : wallet.publicKey
    })
    .signers([wallet.payer])
    .rpc();
```

Answer (score 0):

On the front end, anchor will sign as the provider wallet automatically when you used `.rpc()` or `provider.sendAndConfirm()`. If you want other signers (in this case the PublicKey you made) you will need to add them as well. You'll need to make a Keypair instead:

```
    const keypair = Keypair.generate();
     const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts( {
      sender : keypair.publicKey
     })
    .signers([keypair])
   .rpc();
```

or remove the requirement for the key to be a signer on the Rust side, since there is no reason for that in your example. Sidenote: it's more common to user the Signer type when specifying a signer: `pub sender: Signer<'info>,`